# How to fix connection issue when starting Jupyter kernel for PyTorch?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, conda

I followed the steps in this link to install PyTorch from Conda (Anaconda) :
https://timoast.github.io/blog/installing-pytorch/

I then added the kernel for the virtualenv (cnn) as per the steps in the below link:
https://medium.com/@jeremy.from.earth/multiple-python-kernels-for-jupyter-lab-with-conda-c67e50de3aa3

When I start Jupyter and select the environment for the PyTorch kernel, I get connection failed error with below error messages. Any idea how I can get past this error to have a successful connection to the kernel from Jupyter ? .

```
[I 16:02:20.653 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 81b6a461-87a0-4542-a1c0-b564979c08f2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\mraja\.conda\envs\cnn\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
[I 16:02:23.643 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
```